# Unable to get property '_permissionLevel$p$0' of undefined or null reference

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In my office webaddin some accounts while accessing conversationId from **Office.context.mailbox.item**, it is throwing below error :

> TypeError: Unable to get property '_permissionLevel$p$0' of undefined
>   or null reference

access code :

> Office.context.mailbox.item.conversationId

When it throws permission level error?

Comment: Are you calling Office.context.mailbox.item.conversationId after Office.initialize has been called?

Comment: i have initialised office. this error is coming innative installed windows outlook sometime... not everytime

Comment: Understood that this is in native Windows Outlook. Just to be clear, my comment about Office.initialize is that a Office.initialize method needs to be defined in your addin. APIs will only work after Office.initialize has been called. Please see example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial  The error you see is what we typically see if an API is used before Office.initialize is called, that's why I want to double check.